# No action form POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Is it possible to have an HTML form POST command that does not reload the current page?

I'm writing an SPA using Angular.JS and PHP, and the PHP code creates a PDF file that I want the server to spool to a local printer OR send to the client (depending on the client being a PC or a mobile device), so I believe I need a POST to download the PDF file, but in some cases I don't need the file download, hence I want the server to send a 'do nothing' response to the browser.

I can work around by using an AJAX request first, and depending on the response perform a POST, but was wondering if it was possible to minimise server communication.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to minimize that is used in AJAX ?

Comment: I was trying **NOT** to use AJAX - i.e. if I send an ajax request to build the PDF and then a POST request to download it, that's two trips to the server, so I was trying to build the PDF and optionally send it back if the server did not spool it to the printer, which would only require 1 server request.

Comment: you could give it back as repsonse to  the success method in ajax so it is only 1 request . This situation is perfect for ajax and is only 1 request.

Comment: Thanks Sven, but even if the AJAX request is able to return a PDF (I thought only JSON or XML) I'd have the same problem - how should the server respond if there is no PDF file to download?

Comment: you could return the url if there is a file, if there is no file return false. If false show a message else open the link (google jquery open link)

Comment: Thanks for your persistence in trying to solve my problem Sven, but your suggestion is the same as the work-around I described, in that it takes two requests to the server (one to do the ajax call, one to get the file). That's what I've implemented for now, but I think the iframe route suggested by Nabil is promising, so am going to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe and only the iframe will be reloaded. Here an example :

```
var onDownloadButtonClick = function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('download_iframe_id');
    if(!iframe) {
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.setAttribute('src', '/path/to/your/file/');
        iframe.setAttribute('id', 'download_iframe_id');
        document.getElementById('iframe_parent_id').appendChild(iframe);
    } else {
        iframe.src += ''; // to reload iframe
    }
};

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = onDownloadButtonClick;
```

And in your PHP file, you do something like this :

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'File don\'t exist !';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Nabil - using an iframe would stop a page reload if the file doesn't exist (i.e. deleted in the print spool process), and if I hide the iframe with some CSS then my users wont see the returned error, so I'm going to give that a try.